# Nested cross-validation for classification in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, classification, svm, cross-validation

I am trying to tackle a classification problem with Support Vector Machine in Matlab using SVM. Using sample codes in 
[Bioinformatics Toolbox documentation (SVM Classification with Cross Validation)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ug/support-vector-machines-svm.html#bs3tbev-16) 
, I am able to train a SVM and find its optimal parameters.

But from 
[Inner loop overfitting in nested cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36171/inner-loop-overfitting-in-nested-cross-validation) and [How does one appropriately apply cross-validation in the context of selecting learning parameters for support vector machines?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9354/how-does-one-appropriately-apply-cross-validation-in-the-context-of-selecting-le?answertab=oldest#tab-top),

I will require another outer (leave-one-out) cross-validation to ensure that the final model isn't biased.

My question is, so how do I implement this nested cross-validation? I understand that the inner cross-validation is to choose the optimal parameters, but what is the purpose of the outer cross-validation and how should I do it in code?

Other similar information:

[Nested CV with shrunken centroids and SVM](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/7/91#B7)

[On Over-fitting in Model Selection and Subsequent Selection Bias in
Performance Evaluation](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf)

[How Wrong Can We Get? A Review of Machine Learning Approaches and Error Bars](http://eprints.pascal-network.org/archive/00005011/01/schwaighofer.pdf)

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595176/when-to-choose-which-machine-learning-classifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the outer cross-validation (CV) is to get an estimate of the classifier's performance on *genuinely* unseen data. If the hyperparameters are tuned based on a cross-validation statistic this can lead to a biased performance estimate and so an outer loop, which was not involved in *any* aspect of feature or model selection is needed to determine the performance estimate. 
Conversely if you do not tune the hyperparameters (and use default hyperparameters in `SVM_train` and `SVM-classify`) you do not need an outer cross-validation loop.

Here is an example of some code that will implement nested CV, this implementation uses Nelder-Mead optimization (NMO) and sequential forward feature selection in the inner loop to find the optimum feature set and hyperparameters (box-constraint (C) and RBF sigma).

`Data` are the data to be classified (Dimension: Cases x Features)

`Labels` are the class labels for each case

```
%************** Nested cross-validation ******************
Results = classperf(Labels, 'Positive', 1, 'Negative', 0);      % Initialize the classifier performance object
for i = 1:length(Labels)
    test = zeros(size(Labels));
    test(i) = 1; test = logical(test); train = ~test;
    disp(sprintf('Fold: %d of %d.\n',i,length(Labels)))

    %************** Perform feature selection ************
    z0 = [0,0];    % z=[rbf_sigma,boxconstraint] - set to default exp(z) = [0,0]
    [rbf_sigma_Acc(i) boxconstraint_Acc(i) maxAcc Features{i}] = SVM_NMO(z0,Data(train,:),Labels(train),num_folds);

    %***************** Outer loop CV *********************
    svmStruct = svmtrain(Data(train,Features{i}),Labels(train),'Kernel_Function','rbf','rbf_sigma',rbf_sigma_Acc(i),'boxconstraint',boxconstraint_Acc(i));
    class = svmclassify(svmStruct,Data(test,Features{i}));    % updates the CP object with the current classification results
    classperf(Results,class,test);
    Acc_fold(i) = Results.LastCorrectRate;    
    disp(sprintf('Test set Accuracy (Fold %d): %2.2f',i,Acc_fold(i)))
    disp(sprintf('Test set Accuracy (running mean): %2.2f\n',100*Results.CorrectRate))
end

function [rbf_sigma boxconstraint Acc Features_opt] = SVM_NMO(z0,Data,Labels,num_folds)
opts = optimset('TolX',1e-1,'TolFun',1e-1);
fun = @(z)SVM_min_fn(Data,Labels,exp(z(1)),exp(z(2)),num_folds);
[z_opt,Crit] = fminsearch(fun,z0,opts);
[~, Features_opt] = fun(z_opt);

%************ Get optimal results **************
Acc = 1 - Crit;                       % Accuracy for model  
rbf_sigma = exp(z_opt(1));
boxconstraint = exp(z_opt(2));
disp(sprintf('Max Acc: %2.2f, RBF sigma: %1.2f. Boxconstraint: %1.2f',Acc,rbf_sigma,boxconstraint))


function [Crit Features] = SVM_min_fn(Data,Labels,rbf_sigma,boxconstraint,num_folds)
direction = 'forward';
opts = statset('display','iter');
kernel = 'rbf';

disp(sprintf('RBF sigma: %1.4f. Boxconstraint: %1.4f',rbf_sigma,boxconstraint))
c = cvpartition(Labels,'k',num_folds);
opts = statset('display','iter','TolFun',1e-3);
fun = @(x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test)SVM_class_fun(x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test,kernel,rbf_sigma,boxconstraint);
[fs,history] = sequentialfs(fun,Data,Labels,'cv',c,'direction',direction,'options',opts);

Features = find(fs==1);        % Features selected for given sigma and C
[Crit,h] = min(history.Crit);  % Mean classification error
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would use the package mlr together with mlrChains to implement a wrapper doing the nested cross-validations.

Comment: This is a little brief as an answer - it would appear to be more like a comment as it stands. Can you expand on it? Are you referring to the `mlr` package in R? If so, please note that the question is explicitly about Matlab. If you refer to something else please clarify that.